# Records being randomly deleted

Tags: custom-object, delete, record

I was informed of some weird behavior of some custom records missing from our SF instance and after a little research I found that all of these missing records had been moved into the recycling bin and said it was my user that was deleting them and that it was all occurring by me today even though I hadn't signed on.

What would cause Salesforce to automatically delete your records? Our data storage is a mere 5% and that's the only thing I could think of...

Comment: 0. Reset your password. 1. Check login history. IP. date/times etc. to ensure that no credentials were compromised 2. Figure out what were exact dates of deletion (last modified by). With high probability, there is an automation that is doing it (for example, some trigger or flow, that is scheduled or performed on related records)

Comment: Took all those steps and confirmed that I wasn't hacked, yet I still changed all our authentication stuff. Is it possible that there exists some sort of auto-purge pithing SF?

Answer (score 3):

Salesforce does not "randomly" delete records, not even if you meet or exceed your storage quota (at worst, you would be prohibited from creating new records). You'll want to check for automated processes (Process Builder, Flows, Apex Triggers, etc) that may be deleting these records. You may want to set up some [debug logs](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=code_monitoring_debug_logs.htm&type=5) which could show you which processes are affecting these records.

Comment: I'm not suggesting it randomly deleted them, I'm curious if there is some sort of auto purge settings in SF that removes records if they haven't been touched in a little. I Double checked all automated processes and nothing indicates that a record would just be deleted. What is stranger is that it's been a month or two since we last updated anything with our SF instance, yet this problem just arose within the last week.

Comment: Further more, this only occurred on our Production instance, our sandbox did not have these issues and the codebase is exactly the same

Comment: @BlondeSwan No. There are *auto-archive* options for tasks and events, but this only affects reporting; the records are not deleted. Any deletions were done by some action. Do you have any installed AppExchange apps, or perhaps someone using Informatica or something? If you look at one of these deleted records, what's the Last Modified Date and Last Modified By values?